# Void Century: how can a whole century go by without anyone knowing what happened?

Tags: one-piece

In *One Piece*, it seems like little to no people knows what happened during the Void Century.

How is this possible?

Comment: It was covered up by the world government when they made the world government.

Comment: The void century also happend hundreds of years ago. The goverment destroyed all evidence and killed those who tried to learn it, like the Researchers at Ohara, Robins Homeland.

Comment: there is a real life precedent. we have The Dark Ages which is characterized by a relative scarcity of historical and other written records at least for some areas of Europe, rendering it obscure to historians.

Answer (score 2):

The World Government is heavily protective of whatever happened during the Void Century, and actively seeks to keep people in the dark about it. They burned every book they could find that contained info on the subject, and killed everyone they found who knew about it while preventing as much info from leaking as possible. The Ohara incident is a direct example of that; its inhabitants knew too much about the Void Century to be allowed to live.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 factors that contributed to the fact that no one knows what heppened during the Void Century; Time and Effort.

The more important out of those two is Effort. Specifically, it's the Effort of the World Goverment. The WG has spent centuries hunting and killing anyone who knows anything about what happened. Ohara is one example of this; it was burned to the ground in order to destroy whatever they knew.

The other part is Time. A full 800 year has passed, 800 years during which the WG has hunted/killed anyone who knows anything about the Void Century. It's easy to think that some people here and there would have kept the information, passing it down to their children to safeguard it, but think about the risks of doing so! If you knew that telling your kid about it would see them killed if the WG ever even suspected it, then wouldn't you at least consider keeping silent to protect your children? Over the course of 800 years you have **a lot** of generations that had to face this question.

I find it likely that there were scholars and "old families" that knew stuff about the Void Century for several centuries following it. There were definitely people who knew stuff after 100 years had passed, most likely after 200 years, probably after 300 years, but after 400 years it'd probably gotten rather rare and we're still only halfway to "current time" in One Piece.